# Does the numerical equivalence relation coincide with the homological one for 1-cycles (in positive characteristic)?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, motives, algebraic-cycles, positive-characteristic

Is the Grothendieck's Standard Conjecture D (stating that the numerical equivalence relation for algebraic cycles with rational coefficients coincides with the homological one) known to be true for dimension 1 cycles? I have found a book saying that this result was proved by Lieberman in 1968, so the question is whether the conjecture is known to be true in the positive characteristic case.

Comment: For "homological equivalence", are you looking at the kernel of the cycle class map to $\ell$-adic 'etale cohomology?

Comment: Yes, I do. However, I would be interested in a result of this sort for "any reasonable" (Weil?) cohomology theory.

Comment: Lieberman showed that homological and numerical equivalence coincide for cycles of dimension 0,1,2,m-1,m on a Hodge manifold of complex dimension m, and also that the conjecture is true for abelian varieties. [Sebastian (2013)](http://dx.doi.org/10.1112/S0010437X13007197) has shown that numerical and smash-nilpotent equivalence coincide for 1-cycles on varieties dominated by products of curves. This result has no assumption on characteristic of the base field. Later, he [generalized](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.jalgebra.2015.05.006) his results a bit.

Comment: Thanl you! So, the general case of the statement is not known at the moment.